# How can I continue str.ljust() on a newline?

Tags: python

I am printing out a lot of values using ljust like this:

```py
for cog in bot.cogs:
    cogobj = bot.get_cog(cog)

    try:
        print('+' + '-' * 105 + '+')
        print('| ' + cogobj.qualified_name.upper())
        if cogobj.description:
            print('| ' + cogobj.description)
        print('+' + '-' * 105 + '+')
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    for c in cogobj.get_commands():
        print(f"• {c.name} {c.signature.replace('_', '')}".ljust(35, ' ') + f' {c.help}')
        if isinstance(c, commands.Group):
            for sc in c.commands:
                print(''.ljust(5, ' ') + f"▪ {sc.name} {sc.signature.replace('_', '')}".ljust(35, ' ') + f' {sc.help}')
    print('\n')
```

This will print out something like this

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FUN
| Category with fun commands
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
• embed <title> <description>       Will send an embed with <title> and <description>, who's colour will change every 10 seconds
• channel                           Base command for creating or removing a lot of channels in a guild
     ▪ create <amount> <type> [name]     Will create <amount> of text or voice channels in guild
     ▪ remove <amount>                   Will remove <amount> of text and voice channels in a guild
```

But the problem is that sometimes when the `c.help` or `cs.help` is long, or when I use a `\n` character, it will jump into a new line making it look like this:

```
• eval <body>                       Will evaluate python code and discord.py code.
This means you can basically run any script anywhere anytime.
...
```

When I would like it to look like

```
• eval <body>                       Will evaluate python code and discord.py code.
                                    This means you can basically run any script anywhere anytime.
```

I have tried this with tabulate, but that creates a weird matrix looking table.

So I guess my question is, is there a way to set a max length of a string that automatically joins into a new line with the same ljust?

Comment: did you tried [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module?

Comment: Do you know how many characters are available on the output terminal at coding-time?  Or, alternately, are you willing to impose an arbitrary limit, e.g. 80-character lines?

Comment: @SarahMesser Yeah a limit would be great. It's jumping to a newline exceeding ~135 chars (or whenever I use `\n`)

Comment: @deadshot I have not! I will check it out :)

Comment: textwrap produces almost the same result, though now the help text isn't ligned up properly: https://hastebin.com/iyolezorof.python (are external links allowed)